# My mouse's back button minimizes all windows

Tags: windows-10, mouse, mouse-click, accessories

I've only started having this problem when I hit the back button on my mouse it'll act like I'm pressing Win+D and minimize everything and then reopen them all if I press it again. Sometimes it'll still act like the back button but it's mostly just minimizing. I have tried reprogramming it with X-Mouse but it did not help. The mouse itself did not come with any software.

I have tried looking for drivers but there is no specific ones for this mouse and I have tried testing it on another computer and it works fine

Comment: Remove all the apps that configure mouse button. Try to use mouse control panel i.e. main.cpl

Comment: @Biswa I've tried looking and now my mouse wheel is changing the volume instead of scrolling